# Sort of series values for xAxis

Tags: highcharts

I've two different line charts. One with a datetime xAxis and another one with a linear xAxis.

I've noticed that the order of the series values does not matter, if the xAxis type is datetime. Highcharts matches the values automatically.

```
    series: [{
        data: [[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 29.9], 
               [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 71.5]]
    },
    {
        data: [[Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2), 61.5],
               [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1), 19.9]]
    }]
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/c6hvu/

But in the second chart I've a linear xAxis and two series with values in different orders two. Additionally I've defined categories for the xAxis. Nevertheless the values aren't matched automatically. This results in a charts with wrong values.

```
    series: [{
        data: [{name: 'First', y: 20}, 
               {name: 'Second', y: 50}]
    },
    {
        data: [{name: 'Second', y: 40},
               {name: 'First', y: 10}]
    }]
```

Result: http://jsfiddle.net/xXkPt/

My questions are:

1. Is this behaviour intended or is this a bug?
2. Why does Highcharts matched datetime charts but not linear charts with categories?
3. Is there any way to match the series values for a linear chart too?

Thank you

Torben

Answer (score 3):

Highcharts requires sorted data for xAxis ascending. Open console and see:

```
Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15
```

Highcharts doesn't match categories itself - put there `{name: 'First', y: 10, x:0}` where `x` is an index of category to match. If you don't set `x` value, it is assumed that index of point in `data` array is `x` value.